# Bad quality for my Radial Gradient

Tags: ios, swift

I am drawing a radial gradient in UIView's drawRect function which is pretty simple, the problem I have is that on device (iPhone 6S plus) gradient quality is pretty bad.

Do you have an idea why?

EDIT: I noticed that gradient is bad if my view or color has an alpha value less than 1.0.

```
private func updateGradient() {
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let colors:[CGColor] = [haloColor.CGColor, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor]
gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colors, [0.0,0.8])
setNeedsDisplay()
}

override public func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
if let gradient = self.gradient {
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
let options: CGGradientDrawingOptions = [.DrawsAfterEndLocation]
let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: -70)
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, center, 0, center, size.height*3, options)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: try this self.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale //SUPPORT RETINA

Comment: doesn't change anything. I added a screenshot.